# Embedding youtube videos in Universal Windows platform App

Tags: uwp-xaml, mediaelement

I'm using windows template studio to build a UWP application. In that, I have chosen a treeView template to put my data in. 
My question is how to embed YouTube videos into my treeView page. I'm supposed to save all youtube Url's in my data service file and bind them from my xaml page.

YouTubeId as string.

Using CodeBehind pattern.

I am kind of stuck here.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, choose where you want to put your YouTube videos. I created a windows template studio application and put the **MediaPlayerElement** control into "**CompanyTemplate**" in TreeViewPage.xaml to play videos. Then the item is bound with SampleCompany property by default, so I added the url property in it(e.g. `string VideoPath`). Since the string value can not directlybe passed as the Source of MediaPlayerElement, you need to add [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter?view=winrt-18362) method to convert the string to MediaSource. For example:

.TreeViewPage.xaml:

```
<views:SourceConverter x:Key="MyConverter"></views:SourceConverter>
<DataTemplate x:Key="CompanyTemplate" x:DataType="model:SampleCompany">
    <winui:TreeViewItem AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind CompanyName}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Orders}" IsExpanded="False">
        <MediaPlayerElement Source="{x:Bind VideoPath,Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" AutoPlay="True" Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}"></MediaPlayerElement>
    </winui:TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

.TreeViewPage.xaml.cs:

```
public class SourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {

        Uri pathUri = new Uri(value as string);
        return MediaSource.CreateFromUri(pathUri);
    }

    // ConvertBack is not implemented for a OneWay binding.
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can modify the above examples according to the actual situation.